# PayPal test account Credidentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to use Website Payment Standard for payPal shopping cart chechout. Created business and personal test account in the sandbox. The qustion is that how can i manage the api creididentials for these account. Remember that,when i navigate to the API Credidentials section it tell me that "Your test accounts have not Credidentials"
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered a variety of strange errors with the sandbox environment and all of them went away when I set up a new, pre-configured seller account and set the country to "United States of America" rather than the country that I'm actually in.